# Proxypass from apache to nginx

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, proxypass

How do i convert below proxypass rules from apache to nginx

```
 ProxyPass /symptoms-search  http://medgle.com/symptoms-search
 ProxyPassReverse /symptoms-search  http://medgle.com/symptoms-search
 ProxyPass /ajaxmatch.jsp  http://medgle.com/ajaxmatch.jsp
 ProxyPassReverse /ajaxmatch.jsp  http://medgle.com/ajaxmatch.jsp
```

Answer (score 0):

The following NGINX directives should do the trick:

```
location /symptoms-search {
    proxy_pass       http://medgle.com/symptoms-search;
    proxy_set_header Host      $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}

location = /ajaxmatch.jsp {
    proxy_pass       http://medgle.com/ajaxmatch.jsp;
    proxy_set_header Host      $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

There are plenty of other options you may want to configure, refer to NGINX [http proxy module documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html) for the details.

Comment: i tried above rules but somehow its not working..i am using Nginx version 1.4.1.

Comment: Please share your entire `nginx.conf`

Comment: how do i share my nginx vhost file? can i have your email id so i can forward it you.

Comment: if its not too lengthy then put it in your question please.  otherwise use something like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: i have pasted my nginx conf file on pastebin http://pastebin.com/05UU9dVe. Please have a look and give me a solutions for this.

Comment: i tried your trick also..but somehow its not working.